# how can we make necessary edits to a question that doesn't change enough letters to prevent auto-rejection?

Tags: bug

the title says it all.  it has to do with [this edit](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/15932/revisions) in which all i needed to do was add a couple of backslashes.  but i have run into that problem before.  so i end up changing more than i intended, just to get the system to tentatively accept the edit.

also, with this very question, i am getting "This question body does not meet our quality standards...."

Comment: I think the "This question body..." BS is because the lack of capitals in the question is generally (but not always!) a good indicator of question quality.

Comment: it's not about caps.  and it's not about me editing my own questions.  it's about offering an edit to someone else's question that changes fewer than, i dunno, 5 or 10 characters and that proposed edit is rejected by the crappy SE software because it didn't change enough.  but changing *more* would be an error.  what should we do?  add spaces or other chaff?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake "this very question" I thought referred to this question here on meta, not the one you were editing! :-)

Comment: yeah, i have left very few questions (maybe none at all) outside of the SE meta pages, and it would reject my question based on the caps.  so then i would edit it and put in caps.  after the question posted, i would edit it again to remove caps out of principle (the principle being that of non-acceptance of someone else dictating to me what my own speech or writing is).  but this is different.  we *should* be able to make small corrections in an edit.  like adding or removing the word *"not"* when the meaning of a sentences was negated (like with the *"Wicked Bible"*).

Comment: Agreed! 7654321 :-)

Comment: Just add `&nbsp;` at the end of a line: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014/130885

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it's silly to have to change more than a certain number of letters to qualify as a valid edit.  Leave a typo in because it's a one character change? Those $cos()$ and $sin()$ without the backslash really bug me too.